# CGEvent not fount

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I try to make AutoClicker and I have error "CGEvent" not found. Why?

This is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreGraphics

func click(x: Int, y: Int) {
        
        let mouseDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), mouseButton: .left)
        let mouseUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), mouseButton: .left)
        
        mouseDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
        mouseUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
        
    }
```

I try to find some information about it in Network, but with out response(

Comment: You tagged this with UIKit. Are you trying to do this on iOS or something? `CGEvent` is only available on macOS.

Comment: You have also tagged SwiftUI -- this doesn't have anything to do with SwiftUI